# How to read float number with more digits in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, floating-point, rounding

I'm having issues when I try to read a float number from a file. I need to read 3 float numbers given in a line like this:
v -30.50889491515995 -31.95820181187489 0
(I'm doing a parser from a .obj file from Rhinoceros)

Here is my code (before this I read a string to see if is a 'v'):

```
fstream f(name.c_str());  
...  
f>>p.x>>p.y>>p.z;
```

name is a string readed before from standard input.
P is a struct:

```
typedef struct Point{  
double x;  
double y;  
double z;  
}Point;
```

The problem is that the data readed is:
-30.5089 -31.9582 0
instead of
-30.50889491515995 -31.95820181187489 0
It rounds at 4 decimals, and I don't want that!

I tried to read with fscanf but I can't send it a fstream object. Something like this:

```
fscanf(f,"%f %f %f",p.x,p.y,p.z);
```

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
f>>setprecision(10)>>fixed>>p.x>>p.y>>p.z;
```

Any ideas of how to avoid this? I need more precision in the vertex coordinates!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why didn't work in the second case

Comment: It read the same thing! (rounds at 4 decimals)

Comment: how are you determining what precision the variables have?

Comment: @ruslik that was the problem, I was printing as cout<<p.x<<p.y<<p.z; instead of cout<<setprecision(10)<<fixed<<p.x<<p.y<<p.z; It's solved now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ always inputs the numbers with full precision, but you need to specify the precision for display (i.e. when outputting the values):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("30.50889491515995 -31.95820181187489 0");

    float x, y, z;

    if (iss >> x >> y >> z)
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << std::fixed
                  << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n';
}
```

output:

```
30.5088939667 -31.9582023621 0.0000000000
```

Comment: It helped! The problem was on the cout. I did read with setprecision but when I wrote I didn't use setprecision! It's solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`setprecision` should do what you are wanting to do.  You said it didn't work--what did you get out of it?

Did you try running it in a debugger?  Is it possible that it is not being input properly?

Comment: No, I do a cout and it reads everything ok (except of the rounding thing).

Comment: So does it round when you use cout?  Even if you use `setprecision`?

Comment: The problem was when I tried to output the data (on console or in a file), I forgot to put setprecision in the write thing. Thank you.